# Would you at this situation explain the difference between object and objective as a noun?

Tags: vocabulary

Would anybody please explain the difference between these?

> A government whose **object** is good for people.
>
> A government whose **objective** is good for people.

Is there a difference between these two words when they are used as a noun?

These definitions and citations come from the Longman Dictionary, but I can not yet understand the difference between object and objective at such situations. I am so confused yet.

> **Object**: AIM( the purpose of a plan, action, or activity.
>
> **Object**: the purpose of an action or event.
>
> **Objective**: the thing that you are working towards and hope to achieve by the end of a course of action.
>
> > The object of the game is to score as many points as possible.
> > Nobody knows the real object of their visit. They are keeping it a secret.
> > The object of the game is to improve children's math skill.

Longman also says

> Do not use **object** to mean 'the thing you are working towards and hope to achieve'. Use **objective**: *We have not yet achieved our objective (NOT our object)*.

That appears to mean:

> My **object** is to improve my English as much as possible. (This one is wrong)
> My *objective* is to improve my English as much as possible. (This one is right)

Is my reading correct?

Comment: Incidentally, the *object* or *objective* of government is not 'good for people' - that means, approximately, "healthy or beneficial for them" - but **the good of the people**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:**
In this context the two words mean exactly the same thing. Both are acceptable.

The distinction Longman's draws is difficult to understand; if it means what it appears to mean, it's wrong. I think you may ignore it.

**LONGER ANSWER:**
What Longman's says is this:

> **2** AIM [singular]   the purpose of a plan, action, or activity [↪ goal, aim]
>   **object of**
>
> > *The object of the game is to improve children's math skills.*
> >     *My object was to explain the decision simply.*
> >     *The customer will benefit most, and that is **the object of the exercise*** (=the purpose of what you are doing).
>
> ! Do not use **object** to mean 'the thing you are working towards and hope to achieve'. Use **objective**: *We have not yet achieved our objective (NOT our object)*.

I cannot understand this distinction. It does not reflect actual use of the two words, either now or in the past.

The distinction which **is** drawn in use is exactly the opposite:

- *Object* is used both for purposes and for the person or thing which receives an  action - the Direct Object of a verb:

  > <sup>ok</sup>His **object** is to win Mary's love. ... *The purpose of his actions is to win Mary's love*.
  >   <sup>ok</sup>Mary is the **object** of his love. ... =*He loves Mary. Mary is the person towards whom he directs his love, the person for whom he feels love*.
- But *objective* is used **only** to name purposes. It is not used to name the person or thing which receives an action.

  > <sup>ok</sup>His **objective** is to win Mary's love. ... *The purpose of his actions is to win Mary's love*.
  >   <sup>∗</sup> Mary is the **objective** of his love. ... *This is not acceptable*.

So Longman's is wrong. **Both** of these are correct:

> <sup>ok</sup>My **object** is to improve my English as much as possible.
>   <sup>ok</sup>My **objective** is to improve my English as much as possible.

But only **one** of these is correct, the one with *object*:

> <sup>ok</sup>The **object** of my study is English. ... =*I study English. What I study is English.*
>   <sup>∗</sup> The **objective** of my study is English. ... *This is not acceptable*.

Comment: I am so confused yet.

Comment: @nima_persian Is this any clearer?

Comment: Would you took a look athttp://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168145/would-you-tell-me-the-difference-between-object-and-objective-as-a-noun/168738#168738

Comment: @nima_persian The best answer you've got there is John Lawler's comment immediately below your question. Longman's distinction is artificial and is not followed in practice.